# spring-boot: autowired 2 variables but directing to ONE bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

for example ,there are 2 beans.
parentClass is a generics class

```
// parentClass
@Service
public class ParentService<T> {
    public ParentService(){
        System.out.println("ParentService:   class"+this.getClass()+"  "+this);
    }
}
```

//subClass
subClass extends parentClass and indicates that the generic is a "string" type

```
@Service
public class ChildService extends ParentService<String> {
    public ChildService(){
        System.out.println("ChildService:   class"+this.getClass()+"  "+this);
    }
}
```

// TestCase
autowired the subClass , parentClass that generic is String

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class OneBeanApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private ChildService childService;
    @Autowired
    private ParentService<String> stringParentService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(childService == stringParentService);// true
    }

}
```

the answer is :TRUE
I am confused about that

=====================================
if i edit the test class

```
    @Autowired
    private ParentService parentService;

......

    parentService==stringParentService; // false
```

this is the example project: https://github.com/AshameL/WhyIsSameBean
you can pull it and run the test class

Answer (score 2):

I created one controller class and tried this

```
@Autowired
ParentService<String> stringParentService;

@Autowired
ChildService childService;

@Autowired
ParentService parentService;  // Object class 



@GetMapping("/test123")
public void contextLoads() {
    System.out.println(childService.hashCode()+" : "+stringParentService.hashCode());
    System.out.println(childService == stringParentService);
    System.out.println(childService.equals(stringParentService));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(childService)));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(stringParentService)));
    System.out.println("=====================");
    System.out.println(parentService == stringParentService);
    System.out.println(parentService.hashCode()+" : "+stringParentService.hashCode());
}

OUTPUT:

563182512 : 563182512
true
true
21917bb0
21917bb0
=====================
false
196061929 : 563182512
```

This is expected as when we have `ParentService<String>,` since hashcode is not overriden both Parent and Child class share same Object

In case of `ParentService` default type pass is Object thus different hashcode and so different Object.

**Edit 1:**

During Server Start up I can see following log

```
ParentService:   classclass com.example.demo.service.ChildService  com.example.demo.service.ChildService@2dc6b83f
ChildService:   classclass com.example.demo.service.ChildService  com.example.demo.service.ChildService@2dc6b83f
ParentService:   classclass com.example.demo.service.ParentService  com.example.demo.service.ParentService@349131e3
```

and when I do same with below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParentService parentService = new ChildService();
    ParentService parentService1 = new ParentService();
}

OUTPUT:

ParentService:   classclass com.example.demo.service.ChildService  com.example.demo.service.ChildService@1d44bcfa
ChildService:   classclass com.example.demo.service.ChildService  com.example.demo.service.ChildService@1d44bcfa
ParentService:   classclass com.example.demo.service.ParentService  com.example.demo.service.ParentService@266474c2
```

which conclude that

```
@Autowired
ChildService childService;

@Autowired
ParentService<String> stringParentService;
```

are instance of `ChildService` class due to extend.

Comment: I agree childService and stringParentService are ONE bean as shown in hashcode.what I don't understand is that the childService and stringParentService are different types, why they end up pointing to the same bean.  
TYPE"ChildService" is not equals to TYPE"ParentService<String>".Is it just because the generics of the parent class are defined in the subclass inheritance process?

Comment: added more detail

Answer (score 0):

In java "==" compares object references.

Since ChildService extends from ParentService they essentially might have a reference to the same object in memory, hence you probably get true when comparing them using the "==" sign.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true in the above case.  Spring will create two objects.

Comment: The case is true. I update the question and you can pull it from git .thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default scope in Spring is singleton, so you will get the same instance of `ChildService` with autowiring.